# run saxon xquery over batch of xml files and produce one output file for each input file

Tags: xquery, saxon

How do I run xquery using Saxon HE 9.5 on a directory of files using the build in command-line?  I want to take one file as input and produce one file as output.

This sounds very obvious, but I can't figure it out without using saxon extensions that are only available in PE and EE.

I can read in the files in a directory using fn:collection() or using input parameters.  But then I can only produce one output file.

To keep things simple, let's say I have a directory "input" with my files 01.xml, 02.xml, ... 99.xml.  Then I have an "output" directory where I want to produce the files with the same names -- 01.xml, 02.xml, ... 99.xml.

Any ideas?

My real data set is large enough (tens of thousands of files) that I don't want to fire off the jvm, so writing a shell script to call the saxon command-line for each file is out of the question.

If there are no built-in command-line options, I may just write my own quick java class.

Answer (score 1):

The capability to produce multiple output files from a single query is not present in the XQuery language (only in XSLT), and the capability to process a batch of input files is not present in Saxon's XQuery command line (only in the XSLT command line).

You could call a single-document query repeatedly from Ant, XProc, or xmlsh (or of course from Java), or you could write the code in XSLT instead.